# How do I open all nodes in jquery Jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using the following code:

```
$("#treeview").jstree();
$("#treeview").jstree('open_all');
```

With the following html:

```
<div id="treeview">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">RTB</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" onclick="goTo('index.php?module=alarm&amp;pagina=dashboard&amp;id=6',false);">Beneden</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" onclick="goTo('index.php?module=alarm&amp;pagina=dashboard&amp;id=7',false);">Boven</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My problem is that all nodes stay closed, I can't get them to open with `jstree('open_all');`.

Comment: can you post your generated HTML instead of Smarty?

Comment: **Comment by [@Mr.sinoser](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2845905/mr-sinoser)** `Note: when you use jQuery .on() method you should check your add jQuery core!! because this method is ready on jQuery 1.7 and upper and While the .bind() method existing in jQuery 1.0` (Copied from answers, answer flagged for deletion)

Comment: In my case, it simply worked with the statement `$("#treeview").jstree('open_all');` as indicated in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498683/javascript-jstree-open-nodes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The [jsTree documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation) is "sub optimal". The docs don't clearly state that the initialization works asynchronously. There's [core.loaded()](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core#loaded):

> A dummy function, whose purpose is only to trigger the loaded event. This event is triggered once after the tree's root nodes are loaded, but before any nodes set in initially_open are opened.

This suggests an event `loaded.jstree` is fired after the tree is setup. You can hook into that event to open all your nodes:

```
var $treeview = $("#treeview");
$treeview
  .jstree(options)
  .on('loaded.jstree', function() {
    $treeview.jstree('open_all');
  });
```

Comment: I was having the opposite problem after using this code. I ended up adding another call to jstree('open_all') after the "on" call because chrome finished the tree before the event registration

Comment: Does this answer still work? I can't seem to get it to work for my tree, although it seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: Note atmelino's answer below, on version 3 "ready.jstree" instead of "loaded.jstree" will accomplish the task.

Comment: This did not work for me - check answer below for "ready.jstree" action.

Answer (score 36):

I am using version 3 of jstree and Chrome. The loaded event did not work for me, but the ready event did, even after the jstree instance was created:

```
$('#treeview').on('ready.jstree', function() {
    $("#treeview").jstree("open_all");          
});
```

http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=.jstree%20Event&f=ready.jstree

Comment: This worked for me, whereas the accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 21):

If you want open all node when tree loaded:

```
$("#treeview")
    // call `.jstree` with the options object
    .jstree({
        "plugins" : ["themes", "html_data","ui","crrm","sort"]
    }) 
    .bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
        // you get two params - event & data - check the core docs for a detailed description
        $(this).jstree("open_all");
    })      
});
```

Comment: For the original poster's sake, it helps to give a bit more of an explanation why this would work - i.e. in this case explaining that `.jstree()` runs asynchronously and fires an event when it's ready.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works fine for me, btw, you have an extra }) in the code.

Answer (score 10):

all the answers above not work in my workspace.
I searched again and find this link([Why doesn't jsTree open_all() work for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585527/why-doesnt-jstree-open-all-work-for-me?answertab=active#tab-top)) is helpful, and post my answer:

jstree version: 3.0.0-bata10

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tree").bind("loaded.jstree", function(event, data) { 
    data.instance.open_all();
  });
  $("#tree").jstree();
})
```

Comment: simply bind ready.jstree as atmelino mentioned and problem solved

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the answers here and they didn't work with jsTree (v3.3.4). What worked is the `load_node.jstree` event:

```
    .on( 'load_node.jstree', function () {
      jstree.jstree( "open_all" );
    } )
```

Answer (score 2):

When using html data 'you can set the jstree-open class on any <li> element to make it initially extended, so that its children are visible.' - https://www.jstree.com/docs/html/

```
<li class="jstree-open" id="node_1">My Open Node</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

use simple code

```
$(".jstree").jstree().on('loaded.jstree', function () {
     $(".jstree").jstree('open_all');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply animation to the opening and closing like so:

```
$(document)
    .on("click", "#open-all-folders", function () {
        // param1 set to null to open/close all nodes
        // param2 is the duration in milliseconds
        $("#tree-ref").jstree().open_all(null, 200);
    })
    .on("click", "#close-all-folders", function () {
        $("#tree-ref").jstree().close_all(null, 200);
    });
```

(or similarly apply to `.on('ready.jstree', function() { // code here }` );

Answer (score -1):

```
.bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
        // you get two params - event & data - check the core docs for a detailed description
        $(this).jstree("open_all");
    })
```