# Javascript JStree open nodes

Tags: javascript, jstree

Hello Im using a for loop to open all nodes.

Is there a way to just to open all nodes at once instead of a loop??

```
function (event, data) {
            var myChilds=myfavTree.find("li");

            for(var i=0;i<myChilds.length;i++){
                var myId= $(myChilds[i]).attr("id");
                $("#dataTree").jstree("open_node","#"+myId);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#dataTree").jstree('open_all');
```

Depending on when and how you are trying to do this you may also want to refer to this fairly similar question: [How do i open all nodes in jquery Jstree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018242/how-do-i-open-all-nodes-in-jquery-jstree)

**Update based on clarification:**
If the loop itself is your problem you could try a more specific selector and see if that handles your problem. An id [attribute selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors) should find only the li items with ids. That way your selector engine should be doing the heavy lifting and you can call

```
   var myChilds = myFavTree.find("li[id]")
   myChilds.each(function(){
       $("#dataTree").jstree("open_node",this.id)
    })
```

Comment: I should have been more specific.....I need the nodes with an id opened....there are so many in the array that the javascript gets hung up

Comment: In my case, it simply worked with the statement `$("#dataTree").jstree('open_all');` Thanks!